# Parsing Input Using Expression Tree

Tags: parsing, haskell, io, expression-trees

So I am trying to take a user input and then parse it into an expression that I have set up an expression tree for. The expression tree that I have is:

```
data Expression = State [Float] Float 
                    | Const Float
                    | Plus Expression Expression
                    | Times Expression Expression
                    | Minus Expression Expression
                    | Divide Expression Expression
                    | Uminus Expression
                    deriving(Show, Read)
```

And then I am trying to take the input and then parse it using the following two lines.

```
expression <- getLine
read expression
```

Is there something that I am missing regarding either getting the input or in my use of read? The error that it is giving me is:

```
Main.hs:94:3: error:
    • No instance for (Read (IO a0)) arising from a use of ‘read’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: read expression
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "Input an expression to evaluate"
           expression <- getLine
           read expression
           print ("Hello World")
           ....
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do putStrLn "Input an expression to evaluate"
                 expression <- getLine
                 read expression
                 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use something inside a do-notation, it is in the Monad (or Applicative, if you turn on some language pragmas).

So, your code

```hs
expression <- getLine
read expression
```

is written inside a monad. Then `read expression` is expected to have a type `m a` for some monad `m` and some type `a`. Compiler can infer `m` from the type of `getLine :: IO String`, so `m` is `IO`.

But `read` has type `read :: Read b => String -> b`. Therefore, `b` should be `IO a`. But there is no instance of `Read` for `IO a`, you can't convert a string into an IO action returning something.

The problem is that you want to perform pure computation. To do so you have to use `let`:

```hs
expression <- getLine
let parsed = read expression :: Expression
print parsed
```

Here I use `let` to bind a name `parsed` to the result of `read expression`. Then you have to do something with a value `parsed`, for example, you can print it.

I have to specify the type because `print` can work with anything that has `Show` instance, and the compiler can't select the specific type of `parsed`. If I write something more specific, like `performOperation :: Expression -> IO ()`, then the type declaration can be omitted.

Comment: This worked thank you! The only thing I had to do in addition was just define the type that I wanted it to be parsed into. So:

Comment: let parsed = read expression :: Expression

Comment: I'd prefer `parsed <- readIO expression`, given that we're already in `IO`, as a little habit to get into. `readIO` throws a better exception at a better time when things go wrong.

Comment: @skiboy108 yes, I forgot it. You have to add the type because `print` can work with anything that has `Show` instance, so the compiler needs assistance in type inference. If you do something specific instead of `print` (like `performOperation :: Expression -> IO ()`), then you can omit the type